# DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-04-01T08:53:47.000+02:00 00:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 29

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone-offset, datetimeformatter

Getting a `DateTimeParseExcpetion` when trying to convert the String `2020-04-01T08:53:47.000+02:00 00:00`

```java
String date = "2020-04-01T08:53:47.000+02:00 00:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
parsedDate = LocalDateTime.parse(date,formatter).toString();
System.out.println(parsedDate);
```

Comment: What are the numbers in that string supposed to mean? It looks like someone added an extra `00:00` after the ISO 8601 formatted date and time with offset from UTC (`2020-04-01T08:53:47.000+02:00`). I can’t guess why they did that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern is not the same as your String. Check the last part where is `000+02:00 00:00`.

Your pattern is: `SSSz`

If you try this:

```java
String date = "2020-04-01T08:53:47.000";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

It will works because your date is like your pattern. Note that every number in the date is into pattern too.

But for your date there is an empty space what no make sense, so removing it, the code works perfectly.

```java
String date = "2020-04-01T08:53:47.000+02:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
```

Output:

```sh
2020-04-01T08:53:47
```

Note that `z` is the local time and means "zero hour offset" or "Zulu time" (UTC) and you can use `Locale`.

Answer (score 2):

The  `00:00` at the end of your date-time string doesn't make sense to me. Parse the date-time string after stripping that.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDate = "2020-04-01T08:53:47.000+02:00 00:00";
        strDate = strDate.substring(0, strDate.lastIndexOf(' '));
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime parsedDate = LocalDateTime.parse(strDate, formatter);
        System.out.println(parsedDate);

        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDate);
        System.out.println(odt);
        System.out.println(odt.getOffset());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-04-01T08:53:47
2020-04-01T08:53:47+02:00
+02:00
```

**Note:** You can parse your date-time string (after striping  `00:00` from the end of it) to `OffsetDateTime` in order to preserve the zone-offset information.

Answer (score 2):

### Use the built-in formatter

The built-in `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` matches the part of your string that we can understand. And it can parse just that part and ignore the rest.

```
    String date = "2020-04-01T08:53:47.000+02:00 00:00";
    ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.from(
            DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.parse(date, pp));
    
    System.out.println("Date and time: " + odt);
    System.out.println("Unparsed text: " + date.substring(pp.getIndex()));
```

Output:

> ```
> Date and time: 2020-04-01T08:53:47+02:00
> Unparsed text:  00:00
> ```

Since your string contains an offset from UTC, `OffsetDateTime` is the correct class to parse into. If we used `LocalDateTIme`, the offset would be ignored, and we would end up not knowing at which offset the time was to be interpreted, that is, we could not know which point in time it was. With `OffsetDateTime` the point in time is unambiguous. If you want to convert to the time in your own time zone, convert to `ZonedDateTime` (still not `LocalDateTime`).

```
    ZonedDateTime timeInMyTimeZone = odt.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    System.out.println("Date and time: " + timeInMyTimeZone);
```

Example output:

> ```
> Date and time: 2020-04-01T11:53:47+05:00[Asia/Aqtobe]
> ```

### Links

Documentation links:

- [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME).
- The two-arg [`DateTimeFormatter.parse​(CharSequence, ParsePosition)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,java.text.ParsePosition)) that I used.